# How to use Dart Flutter for desktop and mobile applications

Tags: dart

Can you explain me how to use Dart flutter with just an ordinary desktop web site?

Let's say I have a website, which has a good responsive design, but I want to make it more handy for mobile users. So, I decide to use Dart, I create a server and then? Do I need to redirect users to f.e. m.mysite.com which is built on flutter widgets, but PC users will redirect to mysite.com? Also, there is an information that since June 2019 you can write desktop web application. What does it mean, we couldn't do that before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Randal Schwartz noted, Flutter Web is in very early stages of development (alpha, I believe), meaning you should not roll with it in production. However, it is the **only** way to use Flutter to build websites. You can find it at:

- https://flutter.dev/web
- https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web
- https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/web

If you want to use Dart (not Flutter) in a website, you can try these. They are more mature than Flutter Web, but you'll lose "Flutter" features:

- VueDart (https://refi64.com/vuedart/)
- AngularDart (https://angulardart.dev/)
- React-Dart (https://github.com/cleandart/react-dart) (This one is tricky!)

These are all ports of popular JS frameworks (Vue, Angular, and React) to Dart, so you can use them for responsive website design. Note that you might have to do some background research in the original JS framework, to fill in documentation.

Note: All of the above work on both Mac and Windows. Flutter Web/Dart frameworks are not platform dependent.

Comment: @Petr Schukin could you accept the answer if it's what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has primarily targeted the mobile platform.  What is changing is that Flutter is also being developed for desktop *and* web applications.  Not clear what you mean by "desktop web". Both desktop and web flutter are "not ready for prime time", but progress is being made rapidly.

Comment: Thanks! "By default, Flutter apps are written in Google’s Dart language, which can be compiled to JavaScript." I was just wondering, what's real usage of that. So, we use Flutter to create a mobile app which has kind of web design, and then we can convert it to pure web project?

Comment: Flutter is compiled to native code on the mobile platforms, but to JavaScript for web apps and to platform-native code for mac, linux, and windows.